# JFrame not moving

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, flatlaf

I want my JFrame to move despite disabling Decorrations.

i added a mouseListener after some googling but still didnt help.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new FlatDarkLaf());
        } catch (Exception errorDesign) {
            logError(errorDesign);
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(1600, 400, 500, 800);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            private Point mouseOffset;

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                mouseOffset = e.getPoint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                Point newLocation = e.getLocationOnScreen();
                newLocation.translate(-mouseOffset.x, -mouseOffset.y);
                frame.setLocation(newLocation);
            }

        });

    }
```

someone who knows what i did wrong?

Comment: Did you do any debugging of your code? Did you add a println(...) statement to both methods to see if they are executed? Did you try it with the default LAF? When you find a problem test using standard code from the API to make sure the custom code is not causing a problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

`frame.addMouseMotionListener()` must be used to track motion events such as mouse dragged. The `MouseAdapter` already extends both `MouseListener` `MouseMotionListener` so we can save this into a variable and re-use it in `frame.addMouseListener()` and `frame.addMouseMotionListener()`.

See the Java Tutorial for more help: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new FlatDarkLaf());
        } catch (Exception errorDesign) {
            logError(errorDesign);
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(1600, 400, 500, 800);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        MouseAdapter mouseAdapter = new MouseAdapter() {
            private Point mouseOffset;

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                mouseOffset = e.getPoint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                Point newLocation = e.getLocationOnScreen();
                newLocation.translate(-mouseOffset.x, -mouseOffset.y);
                frame.setLocation(newLocation);
            }
        };
        
        frame.addMouseListener(mouseAdapter);
        frame.addMouseMotionListener(mouseAdapter);

    }
```

Comment: *When you use this listener you can override the mouseDragged method and receive the mouse dragged events.* - which is why I asked to OP to do some basic debugging to understand that only one of the events is being handled. This will teach the OP to verify code is being executed, instead of assuming it is executed. Then if they don't understand why the mouseDragged wans't executed they can ask a more specific question instead of just stating it doesn't work. The question is "what" doesn't work and the OP didn't tell us that.

Comment: On the bright side I can finally review suggested edits. The days of a full suggested edit queue will finally be behind us!!!!

Comment: Got it, updated my answer.